# RDF hash vs slash vocabularies (and the rest)

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, linked-data

I can’t grasp the idea in the case of namespaces and their hash or slash nature. I understand to both of them but I have met another one notation, without a hash or a slash. Particularly in a book I am reading (Mannings: Linked Data) there is a couple of examples using a small schema saved in a Turtle formatted file. These examples use this prefix:

```
@prefix wish: <http://purl.org/net/WishListSchema> .
```

This results in (translation to JSON-LD):

```
 "http://purl.org/net/WishListSchemwish_list_item":
```

In the case I add a hash/slash to the prefix, it looks more reasonably:

```
 "wish:wish_list_item":
```

Maybe I don’t understand properly to the vocabulary/schema difference, I don’t know.

Is the notation **without** a hash or a slash common? Where is the problem?

Comment: Shouldn't it result in `http://purl.org/net/WishListSchemawish_list_item`? (in your snippet, the `a` is missing)

Comment: I know about that error, it seems the last character was dropped because of the whole issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation without slash or hash is not common. I haven't seen a vocabulary using that convention. And in the W3C recommendation they only provide recipees for slash and has URIs: http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/BestPractices/VM/http-examples/2006-01-18/#naming

Actually, if you use the one listed in your example, it may be considered slash notation, but every term in your vocabulary would start with "WishListSchema_".

From the derreferenceability point of view, the example would also lead to problems if you use purl, as you would have to create a different purl for each concept of your vocabulary. Instead, if you use something like http://purl.org/net/WishListSchemwish# you could redirect the URL to you server and use the appropriate recipee for publising the vocabulary.

Comment: Thank you, it is true the variety with hash makes sense because if used, the link directs me to downloading of the schema (ttl).

Anyway, is it common or “allowed” to use such a small vocabulary/schema in a shape of an rdf/ttl/json or so file?

Comment: I don't know if I undestood your question correctly. You can store your vocabularies as you wish. And rdf/ttl is common (I often save them in owl or ttl). But if you want to document your vocabulary (like create an html file), you can enable content negotiation and let the user download either html or your file (which may be on ttl). You just have to follow the w3C link I posted for more info

Answer (score 2):

It is not common and it is not a good idea. The IRIs become harder to read.
Same applies for the `@base` directive, which acts like a prefix - except that, if the IRI used does not have a slash, then the last qname is also dropped:

`@base <http://test.org/path#> .\n <a1> <b1> <c1> .`

parses as an individual with IRI "http://test.org/a1"

Can be seriously confusing, and I don't think it was the best idea for a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

One case where a prefix without the ending character could appear is when the data was originally stored in XML. RDF/XML has traditionally supported treating prefixes as XML namespaces *directly*, so `rdf:` would be declared as `xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"`, with the hash character.

However, there is nothing that prevents declaring other namespaces in RDF/XML. Overly simple tools may then produce a prefix like this:

```
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace>
```

Now, akin to XML, a namespace in RDF is just an abstract grouping of related resources but, unlike in XML, it is not declared anywhere in the RDF data itself. It simply arises when a human inspects the prefixes, but it doesn't exist on its own.

Namespaces become a thing when you actually want the URIs to have a meaning – when the resource is part of a group of related resources (e.g. an ontology) and the URI should be dereferenceable. The hash or slash convention is simply the easiest way to configure a webserver so that this is possible. If someone configures their webserver to treat any URI that begins with exactly `http://purl.org/net/WishListSchema` as referring to that namespace, there will be no issue with that as well.

---

As I sidenote, I don't think this direct conversion from XML namespaces was ever fortunate. XML namespaces weren't obliged to be dereferenceable either, but they were never treated as a prefix in any context, so if there is only a slim chance that `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace#lang` describes something (here it actually does), then `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespacelang` cannot ever be meaningful. In my opinion, a more reasonable algorithm would be to check if the namespace ends with `#` or `/` (which is rare in XML with the interesting exception of `xmlns:`), and append `#` if it doesn't. You certainly wouldn't get 404s when looking for that.